# Entering a date in dd.MM.yyyy will store date in wrong format

Tags: 2sxc

When entering a date with the date picker, the date is not correctly stored.
12. September 2017 will be saved as 9. Dezember 2017
13. September 2017 will not be saved, even if a date is required, because there is no 13. month.
The date picker is presenting the selected date correctly, until it is saved.

DNN 9.1.1 german language pack as default
2sxc 9.4.1

Comment: please show your work.

Comment: could you add more detail? screenshots, code etc.?

Comment: It's simply a date field added to a new app. Just create a new app, create a new entity with date, add an entity and save it.

Comment: It seems to be related to DNN 9.1.1 fresh install. The loglist is displaying the date in mm/dd/yyyy, where all other dates are in dd.mm.yyyy. An updated DNN 8.x is displaying the date correctly. I haven't found a property in DNN where to set this date format.

Comment: It seems the date is stored in EAV as string in the localized format: 01.08.2017 00:00:00, but when the value is loaded, it is parsed as MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss, which e.g is caused by the host thread. I think it is not a good idea to persist the value in a localized string. Better would be to use Culture.Invariant..., then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was already well known and seems to be solved in newer releases:
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1263